# Superposition of Otherwise Identical Waves

Tags: waves, harmonic-oscillator, geometry

In lecture today, the professor was describing the superposition of 2 otherwise identical waves, one modelled by $$y_1(x,t) = Asin(kx-wt+\phi_1)$$ and the other by $$y_2(x,t) = Asin(kx-wt+\phi_2)$$Our prof then said that $$y_1(x,t)  + y_2(x,t) = 2Asin(kx)cos(wt)$$ (He said to choose an $x$ initial and $t$ initial such that $\phi_1 + \phi_2 = 0$ and $\phi_1 - \phi_2 = 0$) This just seems incredibly odd and I'm not too sure how he got there. As far as I know, the identity that applies here is
$$sin(A) + sin(B) = 2sin(A+B)cos(A-B)$$
$$Asin(kx-wt+\phi_1) + Asin(kx-wt+\phi_2) = 2sin(kx-wt)cos(0)$$
$$2sin(kx-wt)$$

Would anyone have any insight as to how my prof could've gotten from this step to the resultant outlined above? Thanks :)

Comment: Are you looking for a proof of the sum to product identities for trigonometric functions?

Comment: $\sin{a}+\sin{b}$ would be $2\sin{\frac{a+b}{2}}.\cos{\frac{a-b}{2}}$

Comment: I think there has been a misunderstanding somewhere. It sounds as if your prof is describing how a standing wave is formed, but this is from two waves moving in opposite directions i.e. $\sin(\omega t - kx)$ and $\sin(\omega t + kx)$. Your $y_1$ and $y_2$ are moving in the same direction and they will not form a standing wave.

Answer (score 1):

The equation $y_1(x,t)  + y_2(x,t) = 2Asin(kx)cos(wt)$ is that of a standing wave which is the superposition of two waves travelling in opposite directions.

You have misheard or transcribed one of the first two equations incorrectly.

Either
$y_1(x,t) = Asin(kx\color {red}+wt+\phi_1)$ and $y_2(x,t) = Asin(kx-wt+\phi_2)$,
or
$y_1(x,t) = Asin(kx-wt+\phi_1)$ and $y_2(x,t) = Asin(kx\color{red}+wt+\phi_2)$

are the two waves, one left-travelling and the other right-travelling, which you need to add to produce a standing wave.

Comment: thank you SO much this makes a million times more sense. Since they're moving in opposite directions, their respective angular frequencies must have opposite signs. Thanks!

Comment: Note that it could also be $(\omega t - kx)$ and $(\omega t + kx)$.